# Quarkus Docker using Jenkins DockerClientException: Could not build image: COPY failed: no source files were specified

Tags: docker, jenkins, quarkus

I'm trying create a Quarkus Docker Image using Jenkins.

I'm using the default JVM dockerFile provided by Quarkus

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.1
ARG JAVA_PACKAGE=java-11-openjdk-headless
ARG RUN_JAVA_VERSION=1.3.8
ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en'
# Install java and the run-java script
# Also set up permissions for user `1001`
RUN microdnf install curl ca-certificates ${JAVA_PACKAGE} \
    && microdnf update \
    && microdnf clean all \
    && mkdir /deployments \
    && chown 1001 /deployments \
    && chmod "g+rwX" /deployments \
    && chown 1001:root /deployments \
    && curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/fabric8/run-java-sh/${RUN_JAVA_VERSION}/run-java-sh-${RUN_JAVA_VERSION}-sh.sh -o /deployments/run-java.sh \
    && chown 1001 /deployments/run-java.sh \
    && chmod 540 /deployments/run-java.sh \
    && echo "securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom" >> 
/etc/alternatives/jre/lib/security/java.security
# Configure the JAVA_OPTIONS, you can add -XshowSettings:vm to also display the heap size.
ENV JAVA_OPTIONS="\
    -Dquarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=${DB_HOST} \
    -Dquarkus.datasource.username=${DB_USER_NAME} \
    -Dquarkus.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD} \
    -Dslack.alert.remote.active=true \
    -Dslack-api/mp-rest/url="some Path" \
    -Dquarkus.mailer.recipients=${EMAIL_RECIPIENTS}"
COPY target/lib/* /deployments/lib/
COPY target/*-runner.jar /deployments/app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001
ENTRYPOINT [ "/deployments/run-java.sh" ]
```

.dockerignore

```
#*
!target/*-runner
!target/*-runner.jar
!target/lib/*
!target/quarkus-app/*
```

and here is the stack I got

```
Step 7/11 : COPY target/*-runner.jar /deployments/app.jar
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Could not build image: COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

prior to that step in jenkins i'm doing the command ./mvnw clean install and then the docker build starts.
[image]

When I look at the workspace in Jenkins, the target folder is there and it contains the lib and the jar file
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

We finally figured it out. To fix the issue we had to move the dockerfile directly to the root of the project and it worked.